# US customs form handed out but asked NOT to fill it out

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, paperwork

Last time I came back to the US from Europe (about 2 week ago), the flight attendants handed out US customs forms and where quite thorough about it, making sure every passenger (other than Global Entry) had one.

However, they were equally insistent that we should not fill it out, just stick it in our passport.

Does anyone had a similar experience and has an idea what this is about? It seems odd to hand out forms and insisting not to actually fill them out.

PS: since I have Global Entry, I didn't get a form and did not see whether anything prepopulated and did not go through any control that would require it, so I don't know what happened downstream. Good thing too: lines at ORD where massive with an average wait time of over 90 minutes.

Comment: Where did you enter the US?  I've found that procedures vary from one place to another.  I usually enter in New York, and after being told several years ago that I needn't have bothered filling out the form I'd received on the plane, I haven't seen one since.  They were not distributed on any of my flights to the US.

Answer (score 3):

This form is *probably* CBP form 6059–B, which looks like [this](https://www.cbp.gov/sites/default/files/documents/CBP%20Form%206059B%20English%20%28Sample%20Watermark%29.pdf). From the various "CFR" numbers at the top of the form, we can see that it is required by [19 CFR 148.13](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/19/148.13), but there is an exception for people who are authorized to make an "oral declaration" under [148.12](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/19/148.12). Broadly speaking, this exception is based on the total value of merchandise that you are bringing into the US.

The practical matter is, unless you're importing a lot of valuable stuff, most people probably do qualify for the oral exception, and will be allowed to enter their identifying information at an electronic kiosk ("[Automated Passport Control](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/apc)"), check a box indicating that they are not importing a lot of valuable stuff, and enter the US without having to itemize their imports at all. If the traveler indicates that they do not qualify for the exception, then the kiosk will prompt them to itemize, and the paper form is still not needed.

You might think this makes the form useless, and it *almost* is. But there's a problem: Not everybody is allowed to use the APC kiosks. CBP's website indicates that "U.S. citizens, U.S. legal permanent residents, Canadian citizens, eligible Visa Waiver Program participants, and travelers entering with B1/B2, C1/D, or D visa can utilize APC kiosks." If you're on any other kind of visa, *and* you don't qualify for the oral exception (i.e. you say "yes" to "anything to declare?" and followup questions indicate that you're over the limit), then you have to fill out the paper form (CBP officers also have discretion to require the form anyway, but they rarely bother). The vast majority of passengers will not fall into this category, and so they don't need to fill out the form.

Based on all of this, I would surmise that CBP is trying to conserve paper and ink, and has asked the airline to tell passengers not to bother filling out the form. The small minority of passengers who do need to fill out the form will likely do it in front of the CBP officer, which won't hold up the line too much as it's a short form and most people won't be filling it out at all.

Of course, it would make more sense for CBP to simply hand out the forms at the checkpoint, instead of making the airline do it, but historically (before the advent of APC), such forms were typical at least at larger airports, and at that time it would've made sense to ask passengers to fill them out in the air. Government agencies, especially in the US, tend to be a bit slow to react to change, so I don't find it terribly surprising that they're still doing things "the old way," especially considering that this particular form has traditionally been handed out by flight attendants rather than government employees (i.e. they would have to coordinate with the airline to withdraw the form).

Comment: I flew from Lisbon to SFO on TAP last week, and Customs Declaration forms weren't even handed out.

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica: It is possible that they have switched to handing them out at the CBP checkpoint as needed. As to why they didn't do that sooner, your guess is as good as mine, but I imagine there's some element of "this is how we have always done it."

Comment: Could be. I wasn't watching the non-US passport lanes. I have Global Entry, and the kiosk seemed not to work. After a few tries, it displayed "See Immigration Officer." I walked over and about 15' before getting to the glass booth, the officer called out my given name. I walked up and proffered my passport; he didn't take it but instead gave me the mean eye and said "Anything to declare?" I said "No," and he said "You're free to go." I've traveled a lot, and never had an entry like that.

Comment: @DavidRemembersMonica: A "no" is an oral declaration consistent with the requirements of 148.12. You didn't have to fill out the form.

Comment: Of course it is. But the interaction with the kiosk seemed aborted: no photo was taken, for example, and the regular questions not asked, and no receipt ticket was printed for me to proffer with the passport when I finally got to the officer. As I said, very different from every other time.

Comment: I understand that some people may have to fill out the paper form. In this case the logical thing to do would to make the form available at the point where that determination is being made. So this doesn't explain handing them out on the plane to everyone and asking everyone to NOT fill it out. I'm afraid the answer to the WHY is simply "government stupidity".

Comment: @Hilmar: On government timescales, the APC kiosks are *relatively* new. There are airports that still don't have any. If you don't have APC, then it makes a lot more sense to hand out the landing cards, because you can greatly reduce the amount of human interaction in the customs process (the landing card asks for identification information, which would otherwise need to be done orally). Most likely this is just a case of continuing to use an old process long after it has been obviated by new technology.

Comment: @Kevin: that assumes that the landing cards are actually filled out, which we were specifically instructed not to do. I fully understand the purpose of a landing card and have received and filled out many of these (for many different countries). However, I've never received a card with the explicit instruction not to fill it out.  It's not an old process: I've entered the US plenty of times and that's the first time I saw that happen.

Comment: @Hilmar: "Well, we've always given the landing cards to the airlines. That's just The Way Things Work. What do you mean we can just *not* do that?" etc.

Comment: I don't want to belabor this too much: the question isn't about landing cards in general, but handing landing cards and than asking people to NOT DO ANYTHING with them.

Comment: @Kevin I've never used APC in the US, and for the last several years I haven't seen those forms.  The last time I saw one was probably 5 or 6 years ago when I handed one to the passport inspector and he said "we don't use those anymore."  I've never had declarations over the personal exemption so I don't know what would happen if I did.

Comment: @Hilmar: It's the US government, man. Every year, they spend tens of millions of dollars making pennies and nickels that cost more than they are worth. I don't know what more you want me to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

This matches my experience when entering the US a few days ago at Minneapolis. The immigration official handed me the usual customs form, however, in Spanish. I went to the customs official to ask for an English copy, but was informed that I wasn't expected to fill it out, but just to hand it to him. This seemed to be how it was done in general: People were handed a customs form by immigration, which they then returned pristine to the customs people.

Comment: Which they then hand out to the next batch of arrivals.  Recycling saves on waste!  Not filling out the form saves on time! It's a win-win situation!

Comment: But why? Is that sort supposed to be a "proof" of having been on an aircraft or having gone through immigration ? The form is easy enough to download and print yourself so its not exactly tamper proof

Comment: We flew into LAX 3 weeks ago, we weren't handed any cards on the flight, breezed through immigration, nothing was asked about customs, forms, anything to declare etc... next thing we knew we were out on the street waiting for the bus.

Comment: @Hilmar I have no clue as to "why", I found it very peculiar as well. I can only confirm that this does not seem to be an isolated case, so the reason would seem to lie on the policy level, rather than the whims of any local official.